# Объясните почему код не компилируется?

Tags: java

я изучаю Java и недавно натолкнулся на пример который не могу разобрать. Объясните почему возникает ошибка?

```
class Cat{}


class Tiger extends Cat{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Tiger> tigers= new ArrayList<>();

        List<Cat> animals = tigers;

    }

}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка должны угадывать? :) Добавьте в вопрос стек ошибки (кнопка `править`)

Comment: наверно функция `main` должна быть вне класса, если это точка входа?

Comment: @gil9red, я думаю, что стека никакого не будет, потому что программа даже не компилируется

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что код не компилируется? Как вы это определили?

Comment: У вас несоответствие типов. Вы листу с типом Cat присваиваете лист типа Tiger. Наследование не работает в дженериках

Comment: @slippyk в Java любая функция должна быть внутри класса (или интерфейса). Вне классов и интерфейсов не может быть вообще ничего, кроме объявления имени пакета, объявлений импорта и аннотаций.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Если вы привели свой код целиком (т. е. это не фрагмент файла, а весь файл), то в начале файла пропущено объявление об импорте классов java.util.ArrayList и java.util.List. Импорт должен объявляться перед началом описания класса таким образом:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
```

Интегрированные среды разработки (= IDE, типа `NetBeans`, `Eclipse` или `Idea`) обычно сами предлагают добавить (или молча добавляют) необходимые объявления, но если вы работаете в простом текстовом редакторе, то могли это пропустить.

2) Далее, хотя класс `List<Cat>` может содержать любых кошек, включая тигров, он не является ни классом `List<Tiger>`, ни его родительским классом, поэтому значение переменной `tigers`, относящейся к классу `List<Tiger>` нельзя присвоить переменной `animals` класса `List<Cat>`.

Подробное разъяснение на сайте Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html